# Confused, Is raspberry pi a real device for learning embedded linux or just for hobby?

Tags: embedded, linux, cortex-a

and sorry i couldn't think of a better title, please read this so you can understand what i am asking:
I already bought the Pi, but as i see it has a fully featured pc like OS, what i'm seeking to learn is embedded Linux programming with Cortex-A to make devices similar to smart fridges smart thermostats drones etc.
In non of the above the user notices that it has Linux unless they check datasheets etc.

how can i learn to do programming like that? its just learning not doing it for hobby or only making things work. do devices like the ones i mention have an os like linux and run the app when being powered with some modifications? im not looking for bare-metal im looking for linux programming, and only experience i have in embedded is AVR and Arduino which are kind of different.

my friend already told me that these devices are just like pi with some modifications to run the app on start, but i saw on some website someone telling that raspberry pi is just embedded-PC and not good for learning!

Comment: The PI is sporting an ARM11, why couldn't you run an "embedded linux" (you should define what you mean by that though, because Ubuntu on a PI is technically one) on it? You can change the OS for something else, it's part of learning. Why not start by Archlinux? It's low level, plenty to learn. The hardware is fine, what you need are good sources to teach you what you want.

Comment: The Pi is definitely a suitable device for learning Linux on, although a lot of the work of booting it from the bare metal is done for you.

Comment: One can choose to run a distro which is more desktop in flavor or a configuration more embedded in flavor.  The pi does have some serious shortfalls, but those concern more the hardware, especially power management and storage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi is an embedded Linux system.  It is running on an ARM and will give you some of the ideas of embedded design.  Whether it is "embedded enough" is a question of how far you want to go.

There are effectively two halves of embedded Linux programming.  In many situations, the developer will wear both hats, but the required knowledge can be slightly different.

1. Systems programming.  This is the part about getting a bootloader working, the kernel building, and driver development.
2. Application programming.  This is writing the actual application that the system is designed for.  This uses the system APIs and userland programming techniques.

The Raspberry Pi is especially well suited for learning the application programming role.  All of the booting and kernel building stuff is done for you, and you can get right to what you need to do.  Some people will deride it as working on a mini-PC, but that is intentional.  It is made to be easy to work with.

On the other hand, Raspberry Pi can also be a platform for learning the systems development side.  This requires a decent amount of hardware knowledge, the ability to read datasheets, and a good understanding of both the processor and Linux boot process.  This is a lot of stuff to learn! But you can take it in pieces since you have a working example.  To learn this stuff, you really need to understand what the developers of the platform have done.  To really get it, you have to do parts of it yourself.  It seems like reinventing the wheel, and it is, but it is **you** doing the reinventing, and you will learn things in the process.

As an aside, I find some professional developers to be very snobby about using "hobby" boards to learn.  I've done professional Linux systems development, and I'm going to tell you it's silly to think that way. We live in a time with amazing access to learning resources.  Learn where you can.

Comment: Thanks so much :) i was confused a lot lately! but Im gonna focus on application programming for now, because i don't think im skilled enough for System programming right now, after getting comfortable with that as much as i am with computers i will move to Systems programming.

Comment: I think is a fantastic path to go.  Good luck!